# BigQuery query for table_type View without parent table's permission

Tags: view, permissions, google-bigquery

I am facing a unique problem. My service account has BigQuery data view permission for a view (table_type). But no permission for parents tables from which view is created. Now, How can I query on the view table without the parent table's permission?

Answer (score 1):

You can use so called [authorized views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views) for this

Giving a view access to a dataset is also known as creating an authorized view in BigQuery. An authorized view allows you to share query results with particular users and groups without giving them access to the underlying source data. You can also use the view's SQL query to restrict the columns (fields) the users are able to query.

See the tutorial for [Creating an authorized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views)

Comment: We are not creating the view. It's already created by the client inside their project. We provide them our service account id. They added our service account id in their dataset which has a view table and authorized view (share dataset).

Comment: so, they (client) need to follow instruction on how to correctly create authorized view for you to be able to use that view without having access to underlying tables. right? :o)

Comment: I recreated the whole scenario for testing using my accounts. It not working with the service account. It's asking for the parent table query permission. Interesting thing it works perfectly for service account if the parent table is a public table.

Comment: authorized views work for service account too. make sure you set all properly though!

Comment: I cross-checked it multiple times. Plz, check the screenshot. There are two views named 'view' (parent table public) and 'view_from_other_dataset' (parent table private). I can read `view` table with same code and permission. but not working for `view_from_other_dataset` table. 

Screenshot link : https://prnt.sc/vxzlko

Comment: see the tutorial for [Creating an authorized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views)

Comment: Great help! I created an authorized view without knowing this.